# Show different images based on cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, onmousemove

I am trying to display five different images depending on the cursor position on the page, only on the x-axis. Picture the page being sliced into five vertical columns and in each column there's another image.

This is my HTML: (imported jQuery in head)

```
<img src="../images/kopf/front.png" id="front">
<img src="../images/kopf/links1.png" id="left1">
<img src="../images/kopf/links2.png" id="left2">
<img src="../images/kopf/rechts1.png" id="right1">
<img src="../images/kopf/rechts2.png" id="right2">
```

and Javascript:

```
<script>

 var mouseX = 0;
 var imageMiddle = document.getElementById("front");
 var imageLeft1 = document.getElementById("left1");
 var imageLeft2 = document.getElementById("left2");
 var imageRight1 = document.getElementById("right1");        
 var imageRight2 = document.getElementById("right2");

$(document).on('mousemove', function getMousePosition(event) { 
mouseX = event.pageX;

if(0 < mouseX < 200) {
    imageLeft2.style.display = "inline";
    imageMiddle.style.display = "none";
} 
else if(200 < mouseX < 400) {
    imageLeft1.style.display = "inline";
    imageMiddle.style.display = "none";
}
else if(400 < mouseX < 600) {
    imageMiddle.style.display = "inline";
}
else if(600 < mouseX < 800) {
    imageRight1.style.display = "inline";
    imageMiddle.style.display = "none";
}
else if(800 < mouseX < 1000) {
    imageRight2.style.display = "inline";
    imageMiddle.style.display = "none";
}
});
</script>
```

Nothing happens when I run this. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: All of your important variables are declared **inside** that "load" handler. They're `undefined` outside of that.

Comment: Ok I changed that, but now only the "imageLeft2" gets displayed. Something wrong with my if condition?

Comment: `0 < mouseX < 200`  you can't chain conditionals like this in javascript.  first mouseX < 200 will resolve to true/false and then 0< true/false will execute, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Cool that helped, thanks! I needed to chain the conditionals like so: 
`mouseX > 0 && mouseX > 200`